# how to force the user to write correctly in HTML input

Tags: javascript, mysql, jsp, servlets, jboss

I have this HTML code in my JSP

```
<table>
      <tr>
                 <td width="50%" > type your article  : 
                 </td>

                 <td width="50%">
                              <input type="text" name="article" size="50"/>
                 </td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

I have in MYSQL database a table 'article' in which i have a column 'designation' , I want to propose a choice of 'designation' to the user according to what is being written.

note: i can not use a dropdownlist because i have more than 1000 designations

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Use jquery lookup

Comment: thanks for ansewring , have an exemple with 'SELECT LIKE % ' request ?

Answer (score -1):

I think you can solve the problem using JQuery Lookup.